# Splice and Arcane combo

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What are the current rules for spliced spells? Can they still be spliced again as long its mana cost is paid? or each spell can be spliced only once? If they an arcane spell can be spliced only once then if it goes to the graveyard the counter is reseted and be spliced again?

For a [Desperate Ritual](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDesperate%20Ritual%5d) + [Past in Flames](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPast%20in%20Flames%5d) combo

EDIT: Thanks for your response everyone.
Now is clear to me that cards that fill the requirements can be spliced only once and as long they are in your hand.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as unclear. It appears to be asking many disparate things, all in very unclear ways, and the core issue (splice + flashback) is not even explicitly asked about in the question. Instead this should be revised to assert a clear scenario of what you are requesting to ask if it is possible.

Answer (score 4):

The rules for *splice onto arcane* (currently the only form of *splice*, and described in [CR 702.46](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Splice)) are as follows:

1. While you are casting an **arcane** spell, if you have a **splice onto arcane** card in your hand (hereafter called a splice card), you may reveal the splice card.
2. If you do, pay the splice cost on the splice card.
3. The arcane spell gains the effects of the splice card.

Nothing happens to the Splice card. It stays in your hand. The original card resolves (plus the splice effects) then, usually, winds up in your graveyard.

You cite [Desperate Ritual](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDesperate%20Ritual%5d) + [Past in Flames](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPast%20in%20Flames%5d) as a combo. You cannot splice onto Past in Flames because it is not arcane. I hope you are instead just planning on using Past in Flames to re-cast an Arcane card from your graveyard.

An arcane spell is a spell with the **Arcane** subtype, i.e. one of these: [`t:arcane`](https://scryfall.com/search?q=t%3Aarcane). These cards all have a type line that reads “Instant — Arcane” or “Sorcery — Arcane”. This means they have the Arcane subtype. This is just like how a Creature may be a Zombie, and cards may care about Zombie cards. The exact same way, splice onto arcane cares about Arcane cards.

If you do happen to cast an Arcane card from your graveyard, such as via Past in Flames, you can still splice Desperate Ritual onto it ***if*** Desperate Ritual is in your hand at the time you cast it.

Comment: I don’t think you addressed the question of if you can use the same splice multiple times.

Comment: (You can’t, but it’s not clear to me why that is from the comprehensive rules.)

Comment: From the Gatherer Rulings:  "You reveal all cards you intend to splice at the same time. Each individual card can be spliced only once onto any one spell."

Comment: @ArcanistLupus Yeah, where I'm getting hung up though is why that is true from the comprehensive rules. I guess it comes down to what the timing window for "as you cast a spell" is...

Comment: @Gendolkari Fair point.  The closest I could find was in 601.2b: "...If the player wishes to splice any cards onto the spell (see rule 702.46), they reveal those cards in their hand. ..."

Comment: Terminology nit-pick: It's splice **onto** arcane, not into.

Comment: So you can't splice from your graveyard using the flash effect because you can't reveal them from your hand?

Comment: @Randoseru That's correct. If you have a card in your graveyard with the ability "Splice onto arcane", then it's in your graveyard, so you can't reveal it from your hand, and thus it cannot be spliced.

Comment: @Randoseru Is that what your question is about basically, splicing from the graveyard by giving the splice card flashback?

Comment: @doppelgreener Yes, using the flash + splice combo the idea was make a huge mana pool and finish the opponent.

Comment: @GendoIkari You can only splice once because the event of casting a spell happens only once (per spell). 702.46a "You may reveal this card from your hand as you cast a [subtype] spell".

Comment: @Hackworth Well 601.2b makes it clear, but if the rules for casting a spell didn't include specifically when a splice card is revealed and used, I would have no idea from "as you cast a spell" when exactly you would do it, because casting a spell is a long, multi-step process, during which there would be many different opportunities to do things "as you cast a spell". Casting a spell isn't like entering the battlefield, which is a specific moment in time.

Comment: FWIW I've decided to vote to close the question as unclear.

Comment: Sorry to make a seemingly trivial edit, but Magic rules are difficult enough to manage the terminology. No hard feelings I hope.

Comment: @corsiKa That's fine. Thanks for that. I've just not revised this since I'm not even sure what the question is doing at this point so I am not sure what I should revise this to say—or it seems to be doing a great many things but not expressing them clearly, or if it is only doing one thing, it is not being clear about that.

Comment: @GendoIkari You were wondering where exactly the CR determined *how often* you may splice per spell, not exactly at which point of the spell casting process. Just because casting a spell is a multi-step process does in no way mean you can splice the same card as often as you want, or do other things multiple times that you do "as you cast x" (which btw is a fairly common wording).

Comment: @Hackworth Fair; I think 614.5 is actually the rule that makes it clear that you can only use it once. It's just not clear from the Splice section of rules; but the general rules regarding replacement effects is clear.